# RStudio does not assign well Help section during building a package

Tags: r, package, devtools, roxygen2

I want to build a `R`package (`RStudio`) with this function:

```
  #' hex2rgb
  #'
  #' Give RGB color code from HEX color code
  #'
  #'  @param color.vector RGB channels datas from PictureResults
  #'  @return results , the name of the matrix
  #'  @examples
  #'  # RGB color code of "Alice Blue" color:
  #'  hex2rgb("#f0f8ff")
  #'  # RGB color code of "Red" color:
  #'  hex2rgb("#ff0000")
  #'  @export
   hex2rgb <- function(color.vector) {code}
```

The package works well but when I build & reload, the `@param`and the others `@` in Help section are putting in `Details`subsection and there are all stick on like that:

@param color.vector RGB channels datas from PictureResults @return resultat , the name of the matrix @examples # RGB color code of "Alice Blue" color: hex2rgb("#f0f8ff") # RGB color code of "Red" color: hex2rgb("#ff0000") @export

I had lunch `devtools`and `roxygen2` before and my R version is `R.3.3.2`.

What can be the origin of the problem ?

Comment: You've got too many spaces between the comment and the `@`s than usual; it's usually only one. I'm not certain if it will screw it up, but it's quite possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Sometimes I think I'm a blind person..